# Need help by using the ResponsiveNav-Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Good afternoon everybody!

I would transfer my normal menu in a responsive-menu with the Plugin from [this site](http://responsive-nav.com/).

**My HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <header>
                <div>

                </div>
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo">L</div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Link4</li>
                            <li>Link3</li>
                            <li>Link2</li>
                            <li>Link1</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My CSS:**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(120, 160, 100, 0.7);
}


header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;

}

.header{
    position: fixed;
    height: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}


.logo{
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}



nav{
    margin-right: 20px;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

li{
    color: white;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: right;
    height: 110px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: inline;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

    font-size: 20px;

}

.content{
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 180px 300px 0px 300px;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT1sv.png

**1.Picture:** Result (over 760px)

**2.Picture:** If the screen size is under 760px I want this result

**3. Picture:** Menu button pressed

I hope you understand what I want and can help me with this plugin or explain me how to use it, I would be grateful for all help I would get :)
Thanks for all your help and excuse my bad english.

Grateful, Nico

Comment: First of all, have you downloaded the plugin and tried it? The documentation is pretty straightforward. The idea is to go step by step. Implement the plugins in it's orginal form. Then after, you can start customizing the CSS to make it blend with your design

Comment: yes I downloaded the plugin and tried it.. but I just get this result: http://imgur.com/Nf0qMMi

I dont know how i can design the menu with this plugin right

Comment: Note, that sometimes a plugin might conflict with your design and is less likely to work properly and adapt itself to it. Sometimes, you can achieve the desired result by custom coding it. I'm never one to back out of a challenge, and also I needed some training in CSS3 transition animations. I wrote a simple code that does exactly the same thing as the plugin, but simplified. I had to re-arrange your CSS and html a bit, but it's not that complicated.

Comment: can you post me the new html and css code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in order to achieve this, I added a hidden responsive menu at the top of the header. I know that it's a duplicate of the existing nav menu (with different CSS tho), and that some might view this as bad, but sometimes, if it's stupid but works, I don't see anything wrong by doing it.

Next, I added a Responsive menu trigger. This pseudo link/button will toggle the display of the menu content.

In the stylesheet, in order to hide the main nav menu and display our trigger button, I added a simple Media-Query that checks if the screen size is lower than 775px.

Finally, in order to toggle the responsive menu, we use a simple jquery click event, some 'CSS Classes' verfification and some CCS3 markup. If the button is clicked, we add an 'active' class to the trigger button and an 'Open' class to the responsive menu. On a second click on the trigger, if the responsive menu is opened, remove the 'active' class of the trigger and remove the 'Open' class. The Open class contains all our CSS3 transition markup to smoothly display the content of the responsive menu.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mvBKQ/3/)

Here is the full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <title>Title Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name=description content="">      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/responsive-nav.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
        <script src="assets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                 $('.rsp-toggle').click(function(){

                    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                        $('.rsp-menu').addClass('menu-opened');
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).removeClass('active');
                        $('.rsp-menu').removeClass('menu-opened');
                    }
                        //stops the browser from jumping to the 
                        //current location, as indicated by the href="#"
                        return false;
                 });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <!-- Hidden responsive menu -->
            <div class="rsp-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <header>
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#">L</a>
                    <!-- Hidden responsive toggle button -->
                    <a class="rsp-toggle" href=""></a>
                </div>
                <!-- Main Nav -->
                <nav class="nav-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>

            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the full CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(120, 160, 100, 0.7);
}


header{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    background: #FFF;
    height: 110px;
}

.logo{
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

nav{
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-menu ul li{
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: right;
    height: 110px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: inline;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-menu ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content{
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 180px 300px 0px 300px;
}

.nav-menu{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.rsp-menu{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 172px;
    max-height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: max-height 500ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: max-height 500ms ease-in;
    transition: max-height 500ms ease-in;
}

.rsp-menu ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.rsp-menu ul li{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.rsp-menu ul li a{
    color:#FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.rsp-menu ul li:hover{
    background: rgba(83, 83, 83, 0.7);
    -webkit-transition: background 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: background 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: background 500ms ease;
    transition: background 500ms ease;
}

.menu-opened{
    max-height: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 500ms ease-out;
    transition: max-height 500ms ease-out;
}

.rsp-toggle{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -999px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 70px;
    height: 55px;
    float: right;
    display: none;
}

.rsp-toggle:before {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Edit this to change the icon color */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "≡";
  text-indent: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  speak: none;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


.rsp-toggle.active::before {
  font-size: 30px;
  content:"x";
}

/*MEDIA QUERY*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 775px) {
    .nav-menu{
        display: none;
    }

    .rsp-toggle{
        display: block;
    }

    .logo{
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nico Pleasure was mine. If you need more infos, don't hesitate to ask. Don't forget to mark the the answer as accepted, as long as it solved your problem that is

Comment: I have some questions, why you use the mini jquery library?
for what is the "max-height" property in .menu-opened in your css?
and in your example you dont use the responsive.js from the plugin, you use only the css from the plugin, is this responisve menu as good as this from the plugin with the originally responsive.js?

I hope you can help me with my questions, grateful nico :)

Comment: @Nico Here are the answers  to your questions. 1) Minified JQuery: the compressed minified file saves bandwidth and improves performance in production. A smaller file size means that once your website has gone live, you will want it to load as fast as possible, so that’s where this squeezed down version comes in. [Source](http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/including-jquery/)

Comment: @Nico 2) Max-height property: Made a little correction to my CSS, I added the height property to '.rsp-menu'. The max-height property in CSS is used to set the maximum height of a specified element. It overrides the 'height' property. This means that height must always be declared if max-height is declared. In this way, at first, the max-height is 0 and the height is 172px. 0 overrides 172, so the menu is not displayed. Once menu-opened class is appended, max-height 300 overrides 0, so the menu is visible [Source](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/max-height/)

Comment: @Nico 3) "You dont use the responsive.js" : Indeed, in fact, I didn't even use the plugin's CSS, this is all custom made and coded to act exactly (or almost) like the plugin. I started from scratch and worked my way step-by-step to emulate the plugin, or should I say, the animation you wanted, but in a more user-friendly way. I guess i could say its as good as the plugin. I found it easier to adapt to your design and html than the actual plugin, who's CSS file was conflicting with yours. I hope these answer your questions

Comment: thanks man, you are really great!
i have one question to the max height, why do you set the max-height on 300px, can I also set it on 500px if I want or less than 300px? what would be different?



and is it possible that we can stay in contact also outside from stackoverflow? because I see you are a guy who is really interested in webtechnology, same as I and I may have a lot of other question in future.. so can you give me your e-mail address or so? :)
grateful, nico :)

Comment: @Nico: The max-height value doesn't have any importance except the fact that it must be greater or equal to the default height value specified in the '.rsp-menu' class declaration, which I set at 172px. I can't remember why I wrote 300px in 'menu-opened', maybe I was testing something. You could write 500px, but it still would always open at 172px (the max) when the 'menu-opened' class is added. But, if you would change the max-height value to 86px, now it would affect the animation. The menu would open and stop a 86px, which is half of 172px.

Comment: @Nico: I appreciate the kind words and it really was a pleasure to help and enlighten you to the best of my knowledge. I'm not really at ease on giving away my email address, I hope you'll understand, It's nothing against you. But if you have other questions, keep using Stack Overflow because it could benefit other people in the future if they stumble upon the same problems or we could use the Stack Overflow chat room. Keep at it, practice makes good. Cheers

Comment: thank you very much, now i understand the property max-height in this example! :)

sorry for that question, sure I understand you! 
how can i use the Stack Overflow chatroom or how can I contact you on Stack Overflow?
greetings, Nico

Comment: My pleasure. The chat room is here: [Stack Overflow Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users). Just find my username, click on it, then click the Start a new room with this user link. Simple as that!